# Page refreshes when hitting a simple button?

Tags: javascript, html

everyone. As you can see i've a form with a button inside. When clicking on the button i want to execute some JavaScript code (not important for this question).

When i'm hitting the delete button, my page refreshes but that's not what i want. Do you guys know why my page refreshes when hitting the button?

**HTML CODE**

```
<form id="form" method="POST"> 
    <button type="button "id="delete" name="delete" onclick="delete_data();"><i class="fa fa-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete Zone(s)</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function delete_data(){
        //this function is used to obtain id's of selected checkboxes.

        var checkedIds = $(".chk:checked").map(function() {
            return this.id;
        }).toArray();

        alert(checkedIds);
    }
```

Comment: because you are submitting the form data put this in form tag attribute action="javascript:void(0)" that is it

Comment: This is also an option to fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prevent the default behavior of happening:

```
function delete_data(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //this function is used to obtain id's of selected checkboxes.

        var checkedIds = $(".chk:checked").map(function() {
            return this.id;
        }).toArray();

        alert(checkedIds);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

event.preventDefault() will help to stop the default behaviour.

```
function delete_data(){
   event.preventDefault();
    var checkedIds = $(".chk:checked").map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).toArray();

    alert(checkedIds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occuring. That's mean it prevents any default browser actions from being executed.

You should add `e.preventDefault()` as the first line in the handler.

```
function delete_data(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        //...
}
```